# Built in Azure Iot-Hub endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm using **IoTHub** F1 subscription and facing following problem:
I'm calling **REST endpoint** for get device list from iothub,
**Ex**: https://my_iothub_name.azure-devices.net/devices?top=10&api-version=2016-11-14

The above **api call** is working fine from postman (postman is ApiAgent)
But the problem is when I'm calling same api from browser it's giving me **405 method not allowed error**.

I've read about it and it's looks like problem with **OPTIONS** request from browsers.

Please throw some lights on this issue,

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to call it with the correct METHOD. In case you are calling from browser, the default method is GET so it's not allowed.

Comment: I call GET method directly but browser internally call OPTIONS method so 405 method not allowed error for that method call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible, first because, from what I see, Azure IoT hub REST API does not issue CORS requests (i.e. they don't write in the CORS header access-control-allow-origin), so your browser client can't access it.